# Counts Based on Multiple condition in OLAP MDX in a single statement

Tags: mdx, mdxstudio

I am stuck with merging different MDX conditions into one single statement on MDX-SSAS.

Details: I have a cube (Acceptance) with following data as below:

```
Uniq_ID        Acceptance_Type        Responsible_Area
   1              Accepted                FrontEnd
   2              Denied                  BackEnd
   3              Accepted                FrontEnd
   4              Accepted                FrontEnd
   5              Denied                  BackEnd
   6              Accepted                BackEnd
   7              Denied                  BackEnd
   8              Accepted                FrontEnd
   9              Accepted                BackEnd
```

Logic:

> (Count of UniqID where Acceptance_type = 'Accepted' and
>   Responsible_Area = 'FrontEnd' / count(ALL))

At this point I have created 3 calculated members in my SSAS to get the Acceptance rate:

**1.**[Count of Accepted] --> Here I just take the count of all members WHERE Acceptance_type = "Accepted"

**Code:** ([AcceptanceType].[AcceptanceType].[AcceptanceTypeID].&[2],[Measures].[count])

**2.**
[Count of Accepted with Responsible area Frontend]
Here I add one more condition of Responsible_area = FrontEnd

**Code:**
([AcceptanceType].[AcceptanceType].[AcceptanceTypeID].&[2],[Measures].[Count of Accepted])
Note that I am using the measure created in 1

3.**[Acceptance Rate]
**Code:**  IIF([Measures].[Count] = 0, NULL, [Count of Accepted with Responsible area Frontend] / [Measures].[Count])
I'm actually chaining the calculated members.
I want to merge all the points 1, 2 ,3 into a single and I'm not able to do so. I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio -SSAS.

Comment: #2 shows you mentioning AcceptanceTypeID again. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one calc like this. Note I made up the Frontend member reference because you didn't have an example in your question:

```
DIVIDE(
 ([AcceptanceType].[AcceptanceType].[AcceptanceTypeID].&[2],[ResponsibleArea].[ResponsibleArea].&[Frontend],[Measures].[count]),
 [Measures].[count]
)
```

Note that DIVIDE is just a shortcut for your `IIf(count=0,,)` code. It should work unless you have an older version of SSAS.